# How to code two Sundays inside two weeks differently?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am saving days in my database but my problem is I shouldn't be able to save the same day.

It successfully saves because they both read "Sunday". How can I code such that the Sunday in the database saved last week is different from "Sunday" today, and so on?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on your data structure? How are you saving the days (and what are you saving them for)? Are you just saving a string in the table field (i.e. "Monday")?

Comment: Yes, just saving a string. I just need a way to identify them that they are different. @Ruslan

Comment: ...since I thought Today.DayOfWeek makes today a unique Sunday.

Comment: Can you have some sort of code (perhaps a job that runs at 12AM every Sunday, or code that would run for each new appointment made starting the upcoming Sunday which would turn back all the current Sundays to a special number? For example, you can use 1-7 for Monday-Sunday and 0 for the previous Sunday? Then each Sunday at midnight you adjust all the existing Sunday's (7's) to be 0's?

Comment: Just to mention it, this sounds like very poor design... I'm assuming your situation requires it (i.e. legacy code and what not), but this is a very dangerous way to design an application. I can explain why if you're interested.

Comment: But yes, I'll try anything to keep reading the days differently. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: I appreciate it. The design is about limiting a user to logging-in once per shift only, where a day has three different shifts, that's the big idea.

Comment: Then you can just have numbered shifts (21 of them) without necessarily tying them to days of week. Each user can have a "last login" date field which you can compare against. If right now is shift #2, and their last login was shift #2, is the last login date earlier than today? Yes - ok good, its a week later. No? its the same shift, prevent login. This sounds like it'd be much simpler...

Comment: From the little information in the question, the use of dates (rather than merely days of the week) would appear to be the correct way forward. If you have a specific reason for not doing that, please expand your question to explain why.

Answer (score 1):

Record meta-data for each save giving the date on which you are saving it, not the day of the week.

Then before you save a new day, verify that you have not yet saved a record for that date.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But is it possible that I use not dates? Is there a built-in function in VB that can automatically detect Sunday today in 5th week of June, unique? Or it can't be helped, I really need to match days with dates?

Comment: Functions for determining whether two dates are unique require you to provide actual dates. Just recording the day of the week is no help. And you can always determine the day of the week from the date.